# How to close all websocket connection on node websocket client before server restart

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have created a websocket client on my node server that listen to a 3rd part websocket server. Communication between client server is all good but the only issue I'm facing is when my server restart socket connection code run again and every time new connection getting established with server that resulting in too many open socket connections. What I want to do is when server restart close all existing open connections then establish new connection.

```
const WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
let sockets = [];
function openSocket(client,id){
client = new WebSocketClient();
client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error 1: ' + error);
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error 2: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
        // setTimeout(run, 1000);
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        let {utf8Data:socketResData} = message;
        // socketResData = JSON.parse(socketResData);
        console.log(socketResData);
    });

    function subscribe(){
        if (connection.connected) {
            connection.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    action: "SubscribeToAuction",
                    data: id
                }
            ));
        }
    }
    subscribe();
    
    function pingServer() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            connection.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    action: "Ping",
                }
            ));
            setTimeout(pingServer, 540000);
        }
    }
    pingServer();

});

client.connect(socketUrl,null,{"x-forwarded-client-id":id},null);
sockets.push(client);
}

function run(){
    axios(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            authority,
            'x-forwarded-client-id': id,
        },
    }).then(res => {

        const auction = res.data.models.HomePageModel.upcomingModel.upcomingAuctions;
        let i = 0;
        for(let el of auction){
            openSocket(`client${i}`,el.auctionUuid)
            i++;
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
run();

setTimeout(() => {
    for(let s in sockets){
        console.log(sockets[s]);
        sockets[s].close();
    }
},10000)
```

Just for checking the possibility I tried to store all the connections in an array then loop through them and tried to close but got this error

```
sockets[s].close();
          ^
TypeError: sockets[s].close is not a function
```

I just want to know what would be the best approach to handle this usecase.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found my mistake instead of pushing client directly I added connection object into that array and now **close()** is working fine

```
const WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
let sockets = [];
function openSocket(client,id){
client = new WebSocketClient();
client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error 1: ' + error);
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    sockets.push(connection); // websockets close methode is available on socket connection object
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error 2: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
        // setTimeout(run, 1000);
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        let {utf8Data:socketResData} = message;
        // socketResData = JSON.parse(socketResData);
        console.log(socketResData);
    });

    function subscribe(){
        if (connection.connected) {
            connection.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    action: "SubscribeToAuction",
                    data: id
                }
            ));
        }
    }
    subscribe();
    
    function pingServer() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            connection.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    action: "Ping",
                }
            ));
            setTimeout(pingServer, 540000);
        }
    }
    pingServer();

});

client.connect(socketUrl,null,{"x-forwarded-client-id":id},null);
}

function run(){
    axios(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            authority,
            'x-forwarded-client-id': id,
        },
    }).then(res => {

        const auction = res.data.models.HomePageModel.upcomingModel.upcomingAuctions;
        let i = 0;
        for(let el of auction){
            openSocket(`client${i}`,el.auctionUuid)
            i++;
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
run();

setTimeout(() => {
    for(let s in sockets){
        sockets[s].close();
    }
},10000)
```